# What happens between sourcing ~/.zsh/env and sourcing ~/.zshrc?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm switching from gnu screen to tmux, and I'm observing a weird behaviour where my shell hangs when I create a new window in tmux.  I can kill the hang and get to my shell if I hit `CTRL-C`, but I want to find out what's going wrong.

I've done some `echo` debugging of my `zsh` configuration and figured out that the hang happens after `~/.zsh/env` is sourced (it doesn't hang w/in `~/.zsh/env`, I've checked that), but before `~/.zshrc` is sourced.  I'm willing to dig further, but I'm not sure what happens between those two steps.  Can anyone tell me, so I know where to look?

Comment: If I'm debugging these things in bash, I turn on verbosity or echo'ing.  For bash, invoke it with `--verbose`.  For tcsh, you use `-x` or `set echo`.  Doing this will print every command before it executes, so you'll know *exactly* which shell command it starts hanging on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah-ha, it's `/etc/zprofile` that's causing the issue.  I found out from `man zsh` the order of the sourced files.  Thanks!